# Unable to delete files in system dir using Java

Tags: java, batch-processing

I am trying to delete a folder and its files in `C:\Program Files\folder\files.` I am not the creator of the folder but I do have admin rights in this very machine I am executing my java code. I am getting IO Exception error stating that I do not have permission to do this operation. So i tried PosixFilePermission to set permission which didn't work either. I have heard there is a workaround using bat or bash command to give admin privilege and execute the batch before deleting the folder. Please let me know if I am doing something wrong or advise on the best workaround.

> Note: file.canWrite() didn't throw any exception while checking the
>   write access. I am using JDK 1.7

```
String sourcefolder = "C:\Program Files\folder\files";
    File file = new File(sourcefolder);
    try {
        if (!file.canWrite())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Delete: write protected: "
                    + sourcefolder);
          file.setWritable(true, false);

        //using PosixFilePermission to set file permissions 777
            Set<PosixFilePermission> perms = new HashSet<PosixFilePermission>();
            perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OTHERS_WRITE);
            Files.setPosixFilePermissions(Paths.get(sourcefolder), perms);
        //file.delete();
        FileUtils.cleanDirectory(file);
        System.out.println("Deleted");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you need to perform an operation running as Administrator.  You can do this from Java using a command line

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
       "runas /user:" + localmachinename + "\administrator del " + filetodelete);
```

You need to read the output to see if it fails.

For me see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771525.aspx

Comment: yes @Peter. I am very sure, its actually a java project folder of course, its not open, neither the files are being used, nor its added to eclipse IDE.

Comment: @JavaLover Does that mean you can delete the files using Explorer?

Comment: yes I can delete the files from Explorer but with a extra prompt asking me to delete as administrator.

Comment: Can you run the java program as administrator?

Comment: how do I do that? could you kindly guide me please?

Comment: You can right click on the program when you start it and select "Run As Administrator" To do this with an IDE, you need to run the IDE as administrator.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @PhilipWhitehouse Good point, I had intended to replace it with an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could be getting a failed delete for a number of reasons:- the file could be locked by the file system, you may lack permissions, or could be open by another process etc.

If you're using Java 7 or above you can use the javax.nio.* API; it's a little more reliable & consistent than the [legacy][1] java.io.Fileclasses;

```
Path fp = file.toPath();
Files.delete(fp);
```

If you want to catch the possible exceptions:

```
try {
    Files.delete(path);
} catch (NoSuchFileException x) {
    System.err.format("%s: no such" + " file or directory%n", path);
} catch (DirectoryNotEmptyException x) {
    System.err.format("%s not empty%n", path);
} catch (IOException x) {
    // File permission problems are caught here.
    System.err.println(x);
}
```

**This is my code to delete you can also refer this:-**

```
import java.io.File;
 class DeleteFileExample
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   
        try{

            File file = new File("C:\\JAVA\\1.java");

            if(file.delete()){
                System.out.println(file.getName() + " is deleted!");
            }else{
                System.out.println("Delete operation is failed.");
            }

        }catch(Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
}

  [1]: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/legacy.html
```

Comment: Thanks @Deepanshu Bedi, for your valuable time. My issue still exists, I can perform this operation if I keep the project in D: or F: or any other driver, but the C: which is write protected. So I am hoping to find a solution to give admin privilege on the fly before deleting the folder.

Comment: Its working if I tried to delete anything in D:../../, its not working if its from C:\Program Files\..\.. which is my original issue.

Comment: That means your program files are allowed some specific tasks. to create folders delete them. etc. try a thing "go to c:\ program Files and right click and tell me what options are you getting? are they limited or it is ok ? now you can also vote :P@JavaLover

Comment: I guess you are expecting me to check what I have in my computer. I am administrator of this account. Now the possible issue is related to the security and I must be a root user to delete this folder. Could you guide me on how I can achieve this by running a .bat command which would allow me to set root privilege, so it will allow me to delete folder? I really appreciate your efforts in this

Comment: You are using windows or mac? [refer this if windows]. i would like an upvote if it solved your problem?(http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/enable-the-hidden-administrator-account-on-windows-vista/)